# How to handle PanResponder long press event?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to handle a long press in React Native via PanResponder. After a decent search I couldn't find how to do it the "right way", so I am asking here. The idea is to execute code when a long press (click) on the screen is detected.
I have come up to something like this:

```
handlePanResponderGrant(e, gestureState){
    // On the press of the button set a timeout
    myVar = setTimeout(this.MyExecutableFunction(), LONG_PRESS_MIN_DURATION);
}

handlePanResponderRelease(e, gestureState) {
    // Clear the timeout if the press is released earlier than the set duration
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Is this the right way to handle a long press or is there a better way?

Comment: `this.MyExecutableFunction()` has to be `this.MyExecutableFunction` and `clearTimeout(myVar)` has to be executed in `handlePanResponderTerminate` as well, to be sure that after press termination the application will not count it as long press.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up doing this functionality with `setTimeout`. Here is the code which has functionality to detect which part of the screen has been long pressed (left or right):

```
handlePanResponderGrant(e, gestureState) {
    console.log('Start of touch');

    this.long_press_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if (gestureState.x0 <= width/2 )
            {
                AlertIOS.alert(
                  'Left',
                  'Long click on the left side detected',
                  [
                    {text: 'Tru dat'}
                  ]
                );
            }
            else {
                AlertIOS.alert(
                  'Right',
                  'So you clicked on the right side?',
                  [
                    {text: 'Indeed'}
                  ]
                );
            }
        }, 
        LONG_PRESS_MIN_DURATION);
}
handlePanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
    clearTimeout(this.long_press_timeout);
}
handlePanResponderRelease(e, gestureState){
    clearTimeout(this.long_press_timeout);
    console.log('Touch released');
}
handlePanResponderEnd(e, gestureState) {
    clearTimeout(this.long_press_timeout);
    console.log('Finger pulled up from the image');
}
```

Comment: Make sure to set `onShouldBlockNativeResponder` to return `false` on the `PanResponder` for Android devices, otherwise, the `PanResponder` will hijack the gesture and not allow normal scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

I have [Carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) inside ScrollView, and I wanted to know where user pressed on the item of `Carousel`. I ended up doing this thanks to @Alexander Netsov.

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => false,
  onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
    this.onLongPressTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("ON LONG PRESS", gestureState);
    }, LONG_PRESS_DELAY);
  },
  onPanResponderRelease: () => {
    clearTimeout(this.onLongPressTimeout);
  },
  onPanResponderTerminate: () => {
    clearTimeout(this.onLongPressTimeout);
  },
  onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
  onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true
});
```

Vertical `ScrollView`, horizontal `Carousel` and `PanResponder`, all are working perfectly fine on Android.

> Note: Its not tested on iOS

Comment: I think you miss on clearing timeout when the user moves (or moves too much).